# Cannot Add needed Traits to an Imported Crate Struct's Constructor Function

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a globally accessible undo/redo functionality in my Rust app via the [undo crate](https://github.com/evenorog/undo).
I start by creating a lazy static which contains my app's data model, `APP_STATE:AppState`, which has field `history` of type `undo::history::History`. My problem is that lazy static requires `Send+Sync` for all of my states field, and while I'm able to define the proper trait  constraints in the `AppState` definition (`history: History<Box<dyn AppAction>, Box<dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync>>`), I don't see any option for adding these traits when I call `History::new()` inside of `AppState::new()`:

```rust
use undo::{History};
lazy_static::lazy_static!{
    static ref APP_STATE: AppState = AppState::new();
}

pub struct AppState{
    names: Vec<String>,
    history: History<Box<dyn AppAction>, Box<dyn FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync>>
    //correct trait constraints
}

impl AppState{
    pub fn new()->Self{
        AppState{
            names: vec![],
            history: History::new(),
            //not sure how to add these trait constraints here
        }
    }
    
}
//..
```

Gives error:

```
history: History::new(),
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait `FnMut(Signal) + Send + Sync`, found trait `FnMut(Signal)`
```

If `History::new()` does not provide any way for me to add `Send+Sync`, does that mean I manually instantiate a `History` struct? What are some work around for this problem?

```rust
impl AppState{
    pub fn new()->Self{
        AppState{
            names: vec![],
            history: History{
                //field 1
                //field 2
                //..
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Definition of the `undo::history::History` struct from the [source code](https://docs.rs/undo/0.46.2/src/undo/history.rs.html#65-71):

```
pub struct History<A, F = Box<dyn FnMut(Signal)>> {
    root: usize,
    next: usize,
    pub(crate) saved: Option<At>,
    pub(crate) record: Record<A, F>,
    pub(crate) branches: BTreeMap<usize, Branch<A>>,
}
```

Comment: The `undo` crate only implements `new` when `F = Box<dyn FnMut(Signal)`. So you cannot use it.

Comment: @Deadbeef so this is something that would have to be changed by the developer? There's no way to instantiate the ```history``` field in AppState as I'm trying to do given the current version of ```undo```?

Comment: The `Record` struct has a [`Builder`](https://github.com/evenorog/undo/blob/bfde64048c35977c8e46dc85ecce7873bd0c2351/src/record.rs#L450) which allows generic function types. Use the `Record` struct to get yourself a `History`.